# IAM Role reference multiple EKS OIDC

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I have 3 different EKS cluster for each stage (dev, staging, prd)
and I need to have multiple IAM Role for each application deployed in our clusters.

The idea is to be able to reference multiple EKS OIDC in the trust relationship of that IAM Role so I would end up with 1 IAM Role per application across clusters instead of 3x.

Configuring one IAM Role + trust relationship is easy like below:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxx-oidc-cluster-1"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxx-oidc-cluster-1:sub": "system:serviceaccount:*:*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is reference my other clusters (`xxxx-oidc-cluster-2` and `xxxx-oidc-cluster-3`) in that same trust relationship. I dug into the official [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html) to how to construct such IAM JSON Policy, but couldn't find anything that could help. I thought maybe I was missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best practice to scope your IAM Roles to one per application per cluster, but if you really want to do this, you'll need to use multiple separate statements in your Assume Role Policy (Trust Relationship).

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxx-oidc-cluster-1"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxx-oidc-cluster-1:sub": "system:serviceaccount:*:*"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxx-oidc-cluster-2"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxx-oidc-cluster-2:sub": "system:serviceaccount:*:*""
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's unfortunate, we need to do it that since we're having multiple EKS clusters (federated ones) for multiple environments (tst, dev, stg, prd). If we don't do the way you've suggested we'll end up having many many IAM Roles :shrug:

Comment: Well, if you’re managing those IAM roles as part of cluster creation or application deployment, i.e., they’re created when the cluster/application deployment is and destroyed when the cluster/deployment is, the number of IAM roles doesn’t matter, it’s their lifecycle that does. Are you using something like Terraform to manage your clusters?

Comment: yep, but we have multiple users that deploy to the cluster and couldn't find a good way to Terraform the IAM Roles creation...