# Allow multiple conditions for IAM Federated OIDC providers for GitHub Actions

Tags: openid-connect, amazon-iam

Similar to [this policy question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68573013/iam-role-reference-multiple-eks-oidc), is it possible to define multiple `ForAnyValue:StringLike` values in the same federed OIDC provider policy statement condition?

Specifically, I am trying to allow multiple subjects from [GitHub Actions OIDC](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect#examples), to allow actions from specific repositories or branches to run actions against an AWS resource.

The `sub` (subject) field is used to [populate the claim](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html#condition-keys-wif).

Using a single value in the condition per the [Configure AWS Credentials Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/configure-aws-credentials-action-for-github-actions#sample-iam-role-cloudformation-template) (i.e. a single repo), works as expected:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::12345678901:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:myorg/myrepo:pull_request"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

whereas using `ForAnyValue:StringLike` with multiple values give the error `Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::12345678901:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": [
            "repo:myorg/myrepo:ref:refs/heads/test-branch-1",
            "repo:myorg/myrepo:ref:refs/heads/test-branch-2"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The policy syntax is correct, the github action workflow was incorrect, I needed to be using `on.push.branches` and specifying the branch names, `pull_request` behaves differently.

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: [ test-branch-2, test-branch-1 ]

jobs:
  tmp:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
    steps:
      # Prepare AWS credentials using OIDC provider (uses id-token and contents)
      - uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_TO_ASSUME }}
          aws-region: eu-west-2
      - run: aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket
```

Comment: A complete example is available as part of a public terraform module I authored on the terraform registry: [github-actions-oidc-role](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/voquis/github-actions-oidc-role/aws/latest)